# Prepending Objects in Alphabetical Order | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, javascript-objects, prepend

I have an array of users whose info is appended or prepended to a list based on their role.

```
if (user.role === 'Student') {
    rosterElement.appendChild(studentList);
} else {
    $(rosterElement).prepend(studentList);
}
```

As seen above, if the user's role is a student they're appended to the list in alphabetical order by last name. And if they're not a student then they're an instructor, who are prepended to the list. However, they're prepended in reverse alpa order according to last name, as shown below.

```
    STUDENT                ROLE
    Jerome Terrell         Instructor
    Priyanka Maheshwaran   Instructor
    Thomas Lee             Instructor
    Angela Lee             Instructor
    Eric Firestone         Student
    Marshall Lee           Student
    Devansh Patel          Student
    Chris Ryker            Student
```

Is there a way to prepend an array of objects in alphabetical order. I've tried using .before() and that successfully prepends the Instructors in alpa order but places them before the *studentList* div thus causing format issues. If you have any suggestions please offer them. Thanks

EDIT

studentList is an instance of a list item(li) being represented in javascript, while rosterElement is the instance of the list(ul). The javascript code goes through the user list and appends or prepends the user's data to the list

Comment: What is `studentList`?

Comment: probably: $(rosterElement).append(studentList.filter(u=>u.role==="Student"),studentList.filter(u=>u.role==="Instructor"))

Comment: Can you show how you’re creating `studentList`, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two divs in it, then append instructors to the first, and students to the second:

```
$(rosterElement).html("<div></div><div></div>");

userList.forEach(function(user){

   $(rosterElement).children().eq(
     user.role === 'Student'?1:0
   ).append(JSON.stringify(user))

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off (both in code simplicity and performance) if you would sort the `studentList` before creating the elements.

As (at the time of writing) there's no example of the contents of `studentList` I'll assume the following structure

`var userList = [
  { name: 'John Doe', role: 'Student' },
  ...
]`

In this case I'd sort the `userList` like this:

```
userList.sort(function(a, b) {
  //  if the roles match, sort by name
  if (a.role === b.role) {
    //  return -1 (a before b), 0 (do not change current order) 
    //  or 1 (a after b)
    return a.name < b.name ? -1 : Number(a.name > b.name);
  }

  //  non-student roles go before student roles
  return a.role !== 'Student' ? -1 : 1;
});
```

In case you need to preserve the initial order of `userList`, you need to know that `sort` will modify that, so you'd need to create a copy (if the list is very large, consider this a performance hit) which is then sorted and used for the rendering;

`var orderedUserList = userList.slice().sort(...)`